# JSON filtering part of data

Tags: javascript, json, api, filter

I need help with filtering JSON data.
I want to get the data from http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson but only the part with coordinates and magnitude. In fact id like brief explanation on how to filter them.

Comment: Please try something and come back here  when you have a specific problem. This is not a coding service.

Comment: I've provided a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25515035/633183) that should help you get started.