# How to filter JSON data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

does anyone know how to filter JSON data in Node.js?

I'm getting sensor data from *Ubidots*, but I just want the latest "value:" from Ubidots and not the whole list of JSON data.

**Node.js Code**

```
var ubidots = require('ubidots');
var client = ubidots.createClient('API Key');

client.auth(function () {
  this.getDatasources(function (err, data) {
    //console.log(data.results);
  });

  var v = this.getVariable('Variable Key');

  v.getValues(function (err, data) {
    console.log(data.results);
  });
});
```

**Output Data**

```
[{ timestamp: 1503473215620,
    created_at: 1503459283386,
    context: {},
    value: 30 },
  { timestamp: 1503393988751,
    created_at: 1503379656112,
    context: {},
    value: 30 },
  { timestamp: 1503386506168,
    created_at: 1503372174737,
    context: {},
    value: 26 },
  { timestamp: 1503386398234,
    created_at: 1503372098148,
    context: {},
    value: 26 },
  { timestamp: 1503386202121,
    created_at: 1503371960322,
    context: {},
    value: 22 },
  { timestamp: 1501487126923,
    created_at: 1501469129791,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487121960,
    created_at: 1501469127666,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487116616,
    created_at: 1501469121192,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487111566,
    created_at: 1501469118178,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487106428,
    created_at: 1501469109047,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487101315,
    created_at: 1501469103976,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487096364,
    created_at: 1501469098454,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487091095,
    created_at: 1501469094217,
    context: {},
    value: 25 }]
```

**This is what I just want it to show**

I just want it to filter to just the latest value as shown below.

```
[{ value: 30 }]
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter JSON data in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514876/how-to-filter-json-data-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#Reduce` to get the highest value.

```js
const data = [{ timestamp: 1503473215620,
    created_at: 1503459283386,
    context: {},
    value: 30 },
  { timestamp: 1503393988751,
    created_at: 1503379656112,
    context: {},
    value: 30 },
  { timestamp: 1503386506168,
    created_at: 1503372174737,
    context: {},
    value: 26 },
  { timestamp: 1503386398234,
    created_at: 1503372098148,
    context: {},
    value: 26 },
  { timestamp: 1503386202121,
    created_at: 1503371960322,
    context: {},
    value: 22 },
  { timestamp: 1501487126923,
    created_at: 1501469129791,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487121960,
    created_at: 1501469127666,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487116616,
    created_at: 1501469121192,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487111566,
    created_at: 1501469118178,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487106428,
    created_at: 1501469109047,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487101315,
    created_at: 1501469103976,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487096364,
    created_at: 1501469098454,
    context: {},
    value: 25 },
  { timestamp: 1501487091095,
    created_at: 1501469094217,
    context: {},
    value: 25 }];
    
const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc = acc.value > curr.value ? acc : curr;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

const {value} = result;

console.log({value});
```