# How do I filter keys from JSON in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to select certain keys from an JSON array, and filter the rest.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(body);
```

which is:

```
{  
   "FirstName":"foo",
   "typeform_form_submits":{  
      "foo":true,
      "bar":true,
      "baz":true
   },
  "more keys": "foo",
  "unwanted key": "foo"
}
```

Want I want:

```
{  
   "FirstName":"foo",
   "typeform_form_submits":{  
      "foo":true,
      "bar":true,
      "baz":true
   }
}
```

I've checked out [How to filter JSON data in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514876/how-to-filter-json-data-in-node-js), but I'm looking to do this without any packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter object properties by key in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750705/filter-object-properties-by-key-in-es6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your obj before passing it to json stringify:

```js
const rawJson = {  
   "FirstName":"foo",
   "typeform_form_submits":{  
      "foo":true,
      "bar":true,
      "baz":true
   },
  "more keys": "foo",
  "unwanted key": "foo"
};

// This array will serve as a whitelist to select keys you want to keep in rawJson
const filterArray = [
  "FirstName",
  "typeform_form_submits",
];

// this function filters source keys (one level deep) according to whitelist
function filterObj(source, whiteList) {
  const res = {};
  // iterate over each keys of source
  Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
    // if whiteList contains the current key, add this key to res
    if (whiteList.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
      res[key] = source[key];
    }
  });
  return res;
}

// outputs the desired result
console.log(JSON.stringify(filterObj(rawJson, filterArray)));
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "filterObj is not defined", yet your snippet is working great. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, got the answer below to work- I'm not sure what made the difference!

Comment: Worked like a charm and I could expand it out to have arrays of key value pairs

Answer (score 5):

Now you can use `Object.fromEntries` like so:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(raw).filter(([key]) => wantedKeys.includes(key)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var raw = {  
   "FirstName":"foo",
   "typeform_form_submits":{  
      "foo":true,
      "bar":true,
      "baz":true
   },
  "more keys": "foo",
  "unwanted key": "foo"
}
var wantedKeys =["FirstName","typeform_form_submits" ]
var opObj = {}
Object.keys(raw).forEach( key => {
   if(wantedKeys.includes(key)){
    opObj[key] = raw[key]
 }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(opObj))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked aways back, but I wanted to just toss out there, since nobody else did:

If you're bound and determined to do this with `stringify`, one of its less-well-known capabilities involves `replacer`, it's second parameter. For example:

```js
// Creating a demo data set
let dataToReduce = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5};
console.log('Demo data:', dataToReduce);

// Providing an array to reduce the results down to only those specified.
let reducedData = JSON.stringify(dataToReduce, ['a','c','e']);
console.log('Using [reducer] as an array of IDs:', reducedData);

// Running a function against the key/value pairs to reduce the results down to those desired.
let processedData = JSON.stringify(dataToReduce, (key, value) => (value%2 === 0) ? undefined: value);
console.log('Using [reducer] as an operation on the values:', processedData);

// And, of course, restoring them back to their original object format:
console.log('Restoration of the results:', '\nreducedData:', JSON.parse(reducedData), '\nprocessedData:', JSON.parse(processedData));
```

In the above code snippet, the key value pairs are filtered using `stringify` exclusively:

- In the first case, by providing an array of strings, representing the keys you wish to preserve (as you were requesting)
- In the second, by running a function against the *values*, and dynamically determining those to keep (which you didn't request, but is part of the same property, and may help someone else)
- In the third, their respective conversions back to JSON (using `.parse()`).

Now, I want to stress that I'm not advocating this as the appropriate method to reduce an object (though it will make a clean SHALLOW copy of said object, and is actually surprisingly performant), if only from an obscurity/readability standpoint, but it IS a totally-effective (and mainstream; that is: it's built into the language, not a hack) option/tool to add to the arsenal.